# gl_PointCoord unavailable on Mac?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I want to make an shader for point sprites - everthing is working on iOS so far. But not on Mac OS X.
My vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec4 color;
attribute vec2 texcoord;

varying vec4 colorVarying;

uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;
uniform float pointSize;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * position;
    colorVarying = color;
    gl_PointSize = pointSize;
}
```

My Fragment shader:

```
varying lowp vec4 colorVarying;
uniform lowp float textureFlag;
uniform sampler2D texture;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = textureFlag * texture2D(texture, gl_PointCoord) * colorVarying + 
    (1.0 - textureFlag) * colorVarying;

}
```

The fragment shader doesn't compile on mac, because of "gl_PointCoord". On Mac I've added an "#define lowp" as preprocessor in the shader.

If I add an "#version 120\n" on top of the shader, it compiles fine on Mac, but doesn't show anything (however on iOS it doesn't work if I'm using an #version tag on top of the shader - maybe, because version 1.2 would miss "lowp").

So, what can the reason be? My Mac says, it uses GLSL 1.2 (I think there was gl_PointCoord added).
Any ideas?!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A GLSL shader that does not have a `#version` directive at the top is assumed to be 1.10. That's probably never what you really want, so *always* use a `#version` directive.

Desktop OpenGL and OpenGL ES are not the same thing. Attempting to feed a ES shader through a desktop GL implementation is not guaranteed to work. So you have to modify the shader accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

A bit of thread necromancy, but i faced the same problem porting some GLES20 code.

The [gl_PointCoord manual](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/gl_PointCoord.xhtml) clearly states that gl_PointCoord is supported in version 1.10, but the GLSL 1.10 spec doesn't even mention that function.

Furthermore, [§1.2 of the 1.20 spec](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.Full.1.20.8.pdf) clearly states that gl_PointCoord support has been added.

So yeah, it looks like the the glsl manual is wrong on this one and support for gl_PointCoord starts at version 1.2.

The troubling part is that some display drivers will happily compile and run a GLSL shader with `#version 110` and calls to `gl_PointCoord`, while others (recent NVidia) will barf a nice `error C7532: global variable gl_PointCoord requires "#version 120" or later`.